# How to add a class depending on screen dimensions with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add a class for an element, depending on the current screen dimensions?

Now I'm using Bootstrap's `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` to handle it, but this requires duplicated code and elements in the DOM.

**Update:**
Overriding Bootstrap's predifined classes is not an option for me. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would just be a hack and is bad practise in my point of view.

Comment: Why you need duplicated code and elements ? If you just want to add a class why you don't do that and call it with mediaqueries?

Comment: would you suggest to use something like `window.screen.availWidth` or is there some "angular-way" to handle it?

Comment: I suggest you don't need Angular at all ... just the use of mediaqueries CSS

Comment: Here is a example of what you need: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: could you give me an example? I need the class `navbar-fixed-top` for small screensizes and `navbar-static-top` for larger ones. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this just use the properties to make it fixed http://www.bootply.com/YrBuu6uTXq

Comment: Use the same class (`navbar-fixed`) with mediaqueries, changing what you need on your dimensions. `@media (max-width:800px and min-width:500px) { .navbar-fixed: width: 20%; } @media (max-width: 1200px and min-width:801px) { .navbar-fixed: width: 40%; }`

Comment: I actually don't want to override Bootstrap's classes, as they're doing a good job. I just want to _use_ them accordingly. I guess it's not a good practise to override bootstrap, is it?

Comment: @DERIIIFranz, I think you are misunderstanding how classes and mediaqueries work. Take a look again in the examples of Bootstrap. The whole point is that you *don't* need to conditionally apply these classes

Comment: Once again: Isn't it considered bad practise to override Bootstrap's classes considering upcoming versions of Bootstrap?

At the moment I'm solving my issue by providing the following function:

`$scope.isScreenXS = function () {
            return window.screen.availWidth < 480;
        };`

Answer (score 1):

You can create directive for that purpose like below, but using CSS media queries seems to be better solution.

Please see here as well http://jsbin.com/mukec/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {




});

app.directive('top', function($window) {


  return {

    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(s, e, a) {
      var body = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("body"));


      $window.onresize = function(event) {
        var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;


        if (clientWidth < 768)

        {
          e.removeClass('navbar-default')
          e.addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
          body.addClass('top50')
        } else {
          e.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
          e.addClass('navbar-default');
          body.removeClass('top50')


        }
      }


    }


  }

})
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: red
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: green
}
.top50 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="navbar" top>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>SCROLL CONTENT</h1>
  <img src="" height="1500px" />
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

May not be best practice but you could write a function that takes the screen size then applies the class

```
function screenLayout() {
   var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}

var classtoadd = angular.element('navbar');
if (clientWidth > 1024) {
 classtoadd.addClass('largeScreen')
} else {
 classtoadd.addClass('otherScreen')
}
```

Could just do it straight javascript or JQuery too

Comment: This is not for AngularJS!